# Object assign overrides previous object when values are the same

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So I am expecting this object when using Object.assign on object1 and object2. There is unknown number of objects 1 - n range.

```
  var expectedObject = [{
         "question": {
            "value": "foo"
        },
        "question2": {
            "value": "foo1"
        },
        "question3": {
            "value": ["fooArray"]
        }
    },
{
        "question": {
            "value": "foo1"
        },
        "question2": {
            "value": "foo2"
        },
        "question3": {
            "value": ["foo1Array"]
        }
    }];

 var object1 = {
        "question": {
            "value": "foo"
        },
        "question2": {
            "value": "foo1"
        },
        "question3": {
            "value": ["fooArray"]
        }
    };

var object2 = {
        "question": {
            "value": "fooIOverrideYouSucker"
        },
        "question2": {
            "value": "fooIOverrideYouSucker1"
        },
        "question3": {
            "value": ["fooIOverrideYouSuckerWonArray"]
        }
    }
var allItems = {}; 

// This will be running inside loop - object1 and object2 are just an examples to simplify the case

Object.assign(allItems, object1, object2);

console.log(JSON.stringify([allItems]));
```

The results I am getting:

```
[{
"question": {
    "value": "fooIOverrideYouSucker"
},
"question2": {
    "value": "fooIOverrideYouSucker1"
},
"question3": {
    "value": ["fooIOverrideYouSuckerWonArray"]
}
}]
```

Is there a nice way to simply append multiple same objects into existing object?

Thank you.

Fiddle with above example.
https://jsfiddle.net/bielus86/fad4w2Lo/10/

Comment: You can do `[object1, object2]`.

Comment: do you want an array as result from two objects? why not take the objects as elements?

Comment: `Object.assign` does not create an array. It's unclear what you're trying to do: if you want to create an array of two identical objects, why not just use `[object1, object1]`? What's the point of merging?

Comment: Apologies for confusion, there is multiple number of objects. Functionality is running inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to create an array with the two objects, you can simply do `[object1, object2]` or

```
var allItems = [];
allItems.push(object1);
allItems.push(object2);
```